# Recalling the value of a previously defined variable and the Today Date inside Export?

Tags: export, string-manipulation

I am using [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)to obtain a.jpg file. I would like that in the file name a specific value (defined as a variable "gama" in the code) appears. I would like to find a way to recall this value so that I don't need to change it every time in the file name inside [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html). I tired with [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html), but the problem is that the command is not recognized because of `""`.I would also like to add the date of today. As an example:

```
Export["/Users/Date_gama_StringForm[NumberForm[gama,3]].jpg", plot]
```

Comment: ``Export[StringTemplate["/Users/Date_gama_`1`.jpg"][
  NumberForm[gamma, 3]], plot]``

Comment: @george2079 what about the Date?

Comment: I have tried: `Export[StringTemplate[
   "/Users/date_`1`-gama_`2`.jpg"][
  Riffle[ToString /@ Date[][[;; 3]], "-"], 
  NumberForm[gama, 3]], plot]` but I am not getting the write format for the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the output shown below help?  It shows the steps in assembling the final complete file name from various strings.  FullForm[] verifies that strings are being made properly.  Will this allow you to put together the file name string you want?

[image]

[image]